# In mPDF is it possible to generate PDFs with fonts as ANSI encoded?

Tags: fonts, mpdf

ANSI encoding would shrink the filesize by half.

Generated by mPDF (88 KB), CID, Identity-H:
[image]

Printed by Acrobat from the PDF in PDF-X1b (47 KB), Ansi
[image]

Asian Fonts are not needed. The fonts must be shown but the file-size should be tiny.

Comment: ??It's MyriadPro and OfficinaSerif ... they have to be embedded as sub-group?? 47 KB is tiny, 88 KB for the same content aren't.

Comment: The first one is generated by mPDF, 88 KB;
In second Screenshot I printed the same file with Acrobat to PDF-X1b. The font-subsetting is different and this means half the file-size. The layout is still the same.

Comment: I had asked my question unclearly, I mean is it possible to get ANSI-Font encoding by mPDF as well. It's the method of encoding for the font sub-setting.

Comment: The manual of mPDF isn't that detailed: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/choosing-a-configuration-v6-x.html

Comment: No need for this, I used this one: $this->percentSubset = 100; This makes sure that font subsetting is always on and my special fonts are needed for the layout. It's really a question of the kind of the font subsetting and how mPDF handles it. Here are some infos: https://blog.pdf-tools.com/2015/05/font-subsetting-how-it-works-and-where.html